# How can I make a jsp table scrollable?

Tags: html, jsp, scroll, html-table

I have the table bellow on a JSP page. The number of rows on the table is variable, populated by a list passed from the controller. How can I add scrolling to it so the table header is fixed? I know it's easy enough on JSF, but how to do it on JSP?

```
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PO</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Batch Size</th>
                <th>SPI</th>
                <th>AOI</th>
                <th>PTH</th>
                <th>Inspection</th>
                <th>Tests</th>
                <th>Expedition</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="prodReportTable">
            <c:forEach var="pojo" items="${list}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${pojo.po}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.productName}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.poSize}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.spi}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.aoi}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.pth}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.inspection}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.tests}</td>
                    <td>${pojo.expedition}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about cross-browser compatibility you can use this style on the TBODY:

```
#prodReportTable
{
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    height:200px;  
    position:absolute;
}
```

Also, you can get rid of the awful row spacing in IE with: (no scroll bar unfortunately though)

```
#prodReportTable TR
{
    height:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out [JQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)?

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this is for table sorting not table scrolling, right?

Comment: sorry, if so you might want to check jquery scrollable table plugin :)   

http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jqgrid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/), which is a jquery table grid plugin. I have used it successfully and it saves a ton of time.  It has sorting, filtering, formatting, paging, and other options.

If you want a somewhat 'lower tech' solution, just make a header div and a body div that is x-scrollable. If that doesn't make sense just let me know and I can send a sample...

Good Luck!